# What vector field property means “is the curl of another vector field?”

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition

I know that a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ is called **irrotational** if $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}$  and **conservative** if there exists a function $g$ such that $\nabla g = \mathbf{F}$.  Under suitable smoothness conditions on the component functions (so that Clairaut's theorem holds), conservative vector fields are irrotational, and under suitable topological conditions on the domain of $\mathbf{F}$, irrotational vector fields are conservative.

Moving up one degree, $\mathbf{F}$ is called **incompressible** if $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 0$.  If there exists a vector field $\mathbf{G}$ such that $\mathbf{F} = \nabla \times \mathbf{G}$, then (again, under suitable smoothness conditions), $\mathbf{F}$ is incompressible.  And again, under suitable topological conditions (the second cohomology group of the domain must be trivial), if $\mathbf{F}$ is incompressible, there exists a vector field $\mathbf{G}$ such that $\nabla \times\mathbf{G} = \mathbf{F}$.

It seems to me there ought to be a word to describe vector fields as shorthand for “is the curl of something” or “has a vector potential.”  But a google search didn't turn anything up, and my colleagues couldn't think of a word either.  Maybe I'm revealing the gap in my physics background.  Does anybody know of such a word?

Comment: “is a coboundary” ?

Comment: @Circonflexe: that would be correct; but my audience is multivariable calculus students and I was hoping there was a physics-inspired term outside of de Rham cohomology.

Comment: As a fallback, you can always use “closed” vs. “exact”, hoping that  1. this will not cause confusion with the case of differential forms, and 2. any such confusion will not be too serious anyway. Btw, thanks for teaching me new terminology...

Comment: Anyway, I lack the intuition about vector fields to help you here, but what is the idea behind the movement of a particle subject to a “coboundary” force? (The idea behind this is that, in degree 1, the mechanical energy will be conserved, hence “conservative” - here, maybe some angular momentum is conserved?)

Comment: @Circonflexe: that's another question I have.  I believe that the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals encapsulates conservation of energy, and the Divergence Theorem does the same for conservation of mass.  That makes me think that Stokes's Theorem is conservation of momentum.

Comment: I see that @Micah has added a bounty.  Thanks for promoting my question.

Comment: I'm a little confused - you wrote "if there exists such a $G$," then $F$ is incompressible. So isn't "incompressible" the word you're looking for? Or one of the other common usages, such as "divergence-free" or "solenoidal"?

Comment: @Jonathan having a vector potential is a sufficient condition for incompressibility but not a necessary one.

Comment: Indeed, but nonetheless, I think it's fair terminology for the purpose of teaching (presumably undergraduate?) multivariable calculus, especially if you're looking for something physics-inspired. Most undergraduate physics in my experience neglects the distinction, where some of the better courses show that the behavior of magnetic fields as $r \rightarrow \infty$ implies $B = \nabla \times A$. Sorry I should have made my assumed context of this (perhaps weak) argument more clear in the previous comment.

Comment: (continued) "These are examples of incompressible vector fields (exercise). Note: there are incompressible vector fields that do not satisfy this property." Alternatively, I have heard physicists just use the terminology "$F$ 'is a curl.'" Or maybe I could suggest the clunky "irrotationless," "irrotation-free." The idea here being that "rotational" indicates the curl being non-zero, but these terms aim to indicate the stronger implication that the irrotational part of the Helmholtz decomposition vanishes. But I don't know if they're already in use.

Comment: @jonathan I think I understand your point now.

Comment: Matthew Leingang Actually, I think in some textbooks that's more an equivalent definition of conservative vector field with the definition you gave as being the definition of a gradient vector field. Then we can say conservative if and only if gradient (under such and such). I think the definition of conservative there is path independence of line integrals.

Comment: @Circonflexe I looked up this question on stackexchange. You gave me the answer I needed even though it wasn't what I wanted. I knew the definition of coboundary but did not understand it as well as I did from your comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Mitjackson The two textbooks nearest to me are Stewart and Marsden/Tromba.  Each of them define conservative to be “is the gradient of a function” then prove that *if the domain is simply connected* that “has a curl of zero” is an equivalent condition.

Comment: Matthew Leingang in line with my previous comment, I think @JonathanRayner is on to something. Calling $F$ with $F = \nabla f$ as a gradient vector field, as some textbooks would do, could analogously lead to $G = curl F = \nabla \times F$ as something like ' curl vector field'.

Comment: @Mtjackson “a curl vector field” is not bad.  I was just looking for something more descriptive of what it does rather than what it is.  I like *conservative* because total energy is conserved along flow lines.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang See Thomas Calculus. They have a different definition of conservative.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks for the 'not bad'. Ah, physics. I find physics so hard that I took up maths. Good for you, physics person. As a maths person, I'm out. Hehe

Comment: @Mitjackson You're right, Thomas uses the “has path-independent line integrals” definition of conservative.  Then his version of the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals shows that *if the domain is path connected* that “is the gradient of a function“ is an equivalent condition.  I'm with you on the physics/math divide.  But my students have a bit more physics intutition and I'd like to speak their language if I can.  Any intuition/motivation helps with these conditions.

Comment: Matthew Leingang, why don't you ask on physics stackexchange and then report back here for any answers? I'm really curious.

Comment: Done: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/514749/52653

Comment: Consensus over there is *solenoidal* because they don't consider situations where $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 0$ but $\mathbf{F} \neq \nabla \times \mathbf{G}$ to be physically realistic.

Answer (score 3):

*Differential geometry answer*: Coboundary (see comment of Circonflexe).

*Elementary calculus answer*: Try 'curl vector field' (see comments of JonathanRayner and myself).

Actually, in some textbooks, e.g. Thomas Calculus, the $F = \nabla f$ is more an equivalent definition of conservative vector field with $F = \nabla f$ as the definition of a gradient vector field. Then we can say conservative if and only if gradient (under such and such). The definition of conservative in Thomas Calculus is in terms of path independence of line integrals.

Calling $F$ with $F = \nabla f$ as a gradient vector field instead of a conservative vector field could analogously lead to $G$ with $G = curl H = \nabla \times H$ as something like 'curl vector field'.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a [pseudovector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector) is quite similar, being associated with the curl of a vector. An apparent generalization is to the concept of a pseudovector field, for which I found a reference [here](https://www.atlantis-press.com/proceedings/amcce-17/25872254). 
There is also the related notion of a vorticity arising as the curl of a vector field but this is not generic.